# Add-on Dev: Extending channel->entries and tagdata

Tags: channel-entries, add-on-development, plugin, extension

I have a search module that grabs locations based on coordinates and estimates distances. I've decided to extend then channel class so I can take advantage of the entries method to display search results. In my method, I use an sql query to find the entry_ids and estimated distance. I then have the following:

```
public function search_results() {
    ...
    $entry_ids = '4|24|265|23';
    $distances = array(
        1.023536,
        1.254824,
        3.000325,
        4.923142
    );

    ee()->TMPL->tagparams['entry_id'] = $search_ids;
    return parent::entries();
}
```

This works great with the following code in my template, with one problem:

```
{exp:module:results}
    <li>
        <span>{distance}</span>
        <h4><a href="/location/{url_title}">{title}</a></h4>
        <div>{my_custom_field}</div>
    </li>
{/exp:module:results}
```

The "distance" is not a channel field, but that calculated value. Any suggestions on how I can inject that into the parsing per row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extension which uses the [channel_entries_query_result hook](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/extension_hooks/module/channel/index.html#channel-entries-query-result) to add your variable to each entry row. That will get parsed along with the native vars. To pass data from your module/plugin file to the extension, you'd need to use the [Session cache](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/session.html#cache-access).

You might be interested to know that [Low Search](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search) offers a straight forward [API for custom filters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/create), which basically extends the channel:entries tag, too. With it, in the same file, you can add your [filter](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/anatomy#filter-method) rules (which you have in your module/plugin file) and manipulate the output of the [results](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/anatomy#results-method) (which you can do with an extension).

Comment: Thank you! That was the route I was planning on looking at today. You saved me from having to find the right hook and then realize the session cache piece.